# Problem with Fracture Modifier deleting changes to mesh

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

If I create a cube, plane or grid and then Edit the vertices so that the vertices are displaced, applying the Fracture Modifier deletes those changes.  The object returns to its original form.

It doesn't make any difference if I apply the Fracture Modifier before or after the changes to vertices.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the fractured mesh after making changes in Edit Mode, you either need to press the "Execute Fracture" button again, or check the "Auto Execute" checkbox so the refracture happens automatically after each change in the edit mode.

Note that depending on the mesh complexity and amount of shards the fracturing can take a bit longer, so I would recommend auto execute only on simpler meshes with less shards.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still not getting it to work.  I create a flattened cube, deform it in Edit Mode into a dome and as soon as I apply Fractures it reverts into a flattened cube.  If I switch to Edit Mode, I see the domed mesh.  In Object Mode I see only a flattened cube.  ???  This happened even after following your suggestions.

Comment: When I apply the Fracture Modifier and it reverts to a flattened cube, it is thicker (Z) than my original.  Are there some presets I need to change?

Comment: OK.  It is working.  Thank you very much.  Not sure what I was doing wrong but starting completely over following your instructions did it.  Thanks!